# How do I adjust the 5-point harness on my high chair so my baby is comfortable?

Tags: infant, feeding

I have a fairly standard 5-point harness setup for my high chair (Graco Slim Snacker), and I've noticed that as my baby gets bigger, his hips start to slide forward in the chair, and the strap that goes between his legs squeezes his crotch so hard that it leaves an imprint on his diaper.

I suspect that this is making him uncomfortable in his chair, and making him anxious when it comes to feeding him.

How should I adjust the straps so that my 10-month old son is comfortable?  I've looked, but I cannot find any kind of guide related to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consumer reports talks about the hight of the straps above a child's shoulders, and how that relates to the amount of movement that a child has in a car seat.

[How to Properly Adjust Your Car Seat Harness](https://www.consumerreports.org/car-seats/how-to-properly-adjust-your-car-seat-harness/)

> If the strap height is incorrect [too low], it can increase the amount a child's body is allowed to move in a crash.

This isn't a car seat, but the same principle applies to all 5 point harness straps, so if the straps on your high chair are on the lower setting, you might try putting them at the higher setting and see if this improves the fit of the high chair.

Comment: The straps are actually significantly higher than my child's shoulders - but I think the problem could be the same, since I know the car seat harness should be flat with the shoulder.